# JavaCompiler with custom ClassLoader and FileManager

Tags: java, classloader, java-compiler-api

I wish to compile source without having the dependencies present on the machine.
Example: File A.java:

```
import some.pkg.B; 
public class A extends B {...}
```

I don't have B source present,  I wish to hook either JavaFileManager or a custom ClassLoader in order to get the symbols in question (the package 'some.package' and class B) and then use a service I have that retrieves the source string.

The compiling code: (inputFiles has A.java)

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
CustomClassLoader classLoader = new CustomClassLoader();
StandardJavaFileManager standardfileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(this, null, null);
JavaFileManager fileManager = new CustomFileManager(standardfileManager, output, classLoader);
CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, this, null, null, inputFiles);
boolean result = task.call();
```

Hooks on JavaFileManager (getFileForInput..) and on my classloader (findClass, loadClass ..) didn't triggered when compiling and I got error messages:

```
A.java:#: package some.pkg does not exist
A.java:#: cannot find symbol
symbol: class B
```

EDIT

After playing around with the API, going over JavaCompiler (older version) source and reading [Compilation Overview](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/doc/compilation-overview/index.html) I still can't find an API hook I can use to provide me Symbols from the syntax trees. It seems that the API needs to get all resources based on package names as suggested by kschneid. 
One workaround I thought about is running the JavaCompiler and analyze the error messages for missing symbols. That way I will know which symbols are needed, get them and recompile.
Any other workarounds / solutions?

Comment: What JDK version/compiler and platform are you using?

Comment: JavaCompiler (javac), JDK 1.6.30 x64 on Windows.

Comment: I am not completely sure. But, I feel as if what you are trying to do is dynamic class-loading. Can't you user `Class.forname()` to load the class at runtime. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Ankit I am trying to compile sources, not load classes

Comment: Just wondering: what is the purpose of doing this? Also, I don't know about bytecode very well but I wonder if it would not prevent you from implementing/overriding methods from B (since the compiler won't have their definitions). In the end I am not sure it would be possible to get runnable bytecode like this, even after loading the real B class…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume that you're not really using a package name of "package" since that would just be illegal...)

Your custom `JavaFileManager` should be getting its `list` method invoked. Hopefully this notation makes sense, but the combination of args to that method should look like this:

```
[PLATFORM_CLASS_PATH, some, [CLASS], false]
[CLASS_PATH, some, [SOURCE, CLASS], false]
[PLATFORM_CLASS_PATH, some.pkg, [CLASS], false]
[CLASS_PATH, some.pkg, [SOURCE, CLASS], false]
```

I'm not sure how difficult it will be for your specific environment to create the appropriate `Iterable<JavaFileObject>` instances, but I think that's what would be required...

Comment: Thanks for the package note, I've revised the question.

Comment: I've missed this function, good call. It is a good path however I don't want to build JavaFileObject to all the classes in the package, just the ones being used in the actual compilation of the Java file I'm trying to compile. Is there a way to get the actual classes names and not just the packages?

Comment: Here is a great implementation for this. http://atamur.blogspot.kr/2009/10/using-built-in-javacompiler-with-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found that a nice way to hook in classes at compile time is with [Groovy AST Transformation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations). You can have a look at what can be done [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-ast-transformations)

That's not plain old java though, but it can be an handy tool to know